# setTransformOriginPoint brings high CPU usage

Tags: qt, paint, cpu-usage, qt4.7

I discovered that my paint function in a custom GraphicsItem takes 100% of CPU (in the worst case)

I found out it was this: 
setTransformOriginPoint

Over all other functions (drawRect, set Hight Quality antialias, etc).

The funny thing is that i removed it, and everything worked fine. I put it after a translate, so supposedly it would rotate related to that new transform origin point. But it worked anyway... I wonder why...

But the main question is: Why 100%?

I give you the code for the paint of the item giving that high cpu usage:

```
// Translate all to the center of the ruler calculated in the itemChange method.
  painter->translate(rulerCenter_);
  // rotate with the center where the ruler center is
  //setTransformOriginPoint(rulerCenter_); <-- BRINGS 100% USAGE, NO SENSE WHY IT WORKS WITHOUT THIS.

  painter->rotate(rulerRotation_);

  // Set the color for the lines and quality of the lines
  painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
  painter->setPen(linesColor_);

  // Draw long line of the ruler next to the wall
  painter->drawLine(-length_/2,0,length_/2,0);

  // Lines in the sides
  painter->drawLine(-length_/2, 0, -length_/2, -sideLinesSize_); 
  painter->drawLine(length_/2, 0, length_/2, -sideLinesSize_); 

  // if we should flip the text for the user to read it properly...
  if (flippedText_)
    painter->rotate(180);

  // Prepare for the text box, moving it to be centered
  painter->translate(-textBox_.width()/2,-textBox_.height()/2);

  // draw a box under the text so it hides whatever is under it
  painter->setBrush(textBackgroundColor_);
  painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
  painter->drawRect(textBox_);

  // Draw the text
  painter->setPen(pen_);
  painter->setFont(font_);
  painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing, true);
  painter->drawText(textBox_, Qt::AlignCenter, meassureString_ );
```

Comment: Why would you call `setTransformOriginPoint()` inside the paint function?

Answer (score 1):

You should be separating rendering from all other processing tasks.

The paint function is just for painting an item, not for moving or rotating objects. If you try to do anything other than rendering in the paint function, you'll either delay or stall the graphics pipeline. This is likely to be what is happening when you call setTransformOriginPoint.

Setting up the graphics pipeline before rendering takes a considerable amount of processing. If you stall the pipeline, it has to do it again, which would account for the 100% processor time.

Although it describes what's happening in an ARM processor, the [theory explained is the same here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0555a/CHDHEHIE.html).

Comment: Thanks! But i don´t understand... I position the items, because everytime i paint an item, or a complex item made by other items, the painter is reset, so i have to move the brush all the time and draw the lines, rotate, draw another line, etc...  I know the positions but i have to reload them everytime i paint!

Comment: If you add example code of your paint function to your question I'll explain the problem relative to that.

Comment: Ok, so all your other calls perform rotation / translation via the painter, which is fine. As I see it, the problem you have is that before any paint function is called I expect the system has a few things to setup based upon the GraphicsItem's internal matrix (local position and orientation). Once done, it can then call the item's paint function. However, by calling setTransformOrigin in the paint function, the matrix of the GraphicsItem changes during rendering, which stalls the graphics pipeline as it must set up again for that item.